# Finding path length along points in postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgis database (postgres 8.4.11, postgis 1.5.2) with gps-observations where I would like to calculate some travel distances.

I calculate the travelled distance from one point to another one hour later with 
select observedid,ST_Distance(p1.shape_utm,p2.shape_utm) from gpspoint p1, gpspoint p2 where p2.datetime=p1.datetime+interval '1 hour'

(and of course a bit more, but this is the distance part in it) I have defined this as a view so that I can easily do a 
select * from movement_view where observedid=42

Question 1:
Is it possible to make the view so that I can define the time interval as well?

e.g. select * form movement_view where observedid=42 and interval='15 minutes' ?

Question 2:
Is it possible in SQL/postgis to calculate the total distance travelled for a period of time? I have a gpspoint each 5th second and would like to calculate travelled distance for e.g. 1 hour following each gps-point. I can calculate the travelled distance for each point using the same method as above, and then I may be able to use the sum() function, but how?

Table definition: 
id integer,
gpsstatus character(2),
datetime timestamp without time zone,
lat numeric(9,6),
lon numeric(9,6),
alt numeric(9,4),
time integer,
datafileid integer,
shape geometry,
speed double precision,
dist double precision,
shape_utm geometry,
lokalitet character(128),
cowid integer

Id: Primary key There are indexes on datetime,lokalitet,cowid,gpsstatus, gist-index on shape and shape_utm.

Comment: Sorry, slightly wron title, a better one would have been "finding length of path along points in postgis"

Comment: bah, tried to remove the comment after I discovered that I could edit the title, but too late...

Comment: answer is yes to both, it's relatively easy to create a subquery that has key, distance between two points for each set of points and then sum those results.   I added a postgresql tag as your answer is more sql then it is geo...more views this way.  If you give table schema info, you'll probably get a working answer.

Comment: Thanks @Twelfth. You're probably right about the postgres-tag. I was thinking postgis due to the distance, but in reallity, it's just a "normal" summing (as soon as I have done the st_distance part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

```
CREATE VIEW movement_view AS
SELECT observedid, ST_Distance(p1.shape_utm,p2.shape_utm) as distance, p1.datetime as datetime1, p2.datetime as datetime2
FROM gpspoint p1, gpspoint p2;

SELECT * from movement_view where observedid = 42 and datetime2 = datetime1 + interval '15 minutes'
```

Question 2:

Create a line from your points and calculate the length:

```
SELECT hours,  st_Length(ST_MakeLine(t.shape_utm)) as distance FROM
    (SELECT date_trunc('hour', datetime::timestamp) as hours, shape_utm FROM gpspoint order by datetime) as t
GROUP by hours
```

Comment: Thanks @user1410317 , obiously didn't think along the right lines for the view...  Have to look a bit more into the other answer

Comment: Notice that I made a mistake. in second querry it should be ST_length, not st_distance. Corrected it already.